# Changing Firebase Package Name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a app with Google Sign-In integrated with Firebase. I recently changed app package name for release purpose. and now running throwing this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name '<Package Name>'
```

So I am guessing Firebase cant recognize app with the new package name. How can I change Firebase package name. I have gone through Firebase console but can't find any changing package settings. Or is there any good way to achieve this instead of creating new project with package name and code again? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add another app with new package to your Firebase project.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As Eurosecom commented, you can just add a new Android app to your existing Firebase project with the new package name. After doing this, download the updated google-services.json and add it to your app.

Note that Firebase does not use the actual package name from your Java code, but uses the applicationId from your app's build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.firebase.hearthchat"
```

When you initially create a project in Android Studio, the package name and application id will have the same value. But if you refactor your code into a different package, the application id won't be updated. That explains why the app will continue to work after such a refactoring. But it can be confusing at times, which is why I prefer keeping them in sync.

Comment: Do you need to re-add all the SHA1 keys and other things? Or do I simply do EXACTLY what you did?

Comment: Related to that question, is it possible to have sort of a Wildcard package name for Google Sign-In? Because I was thinking that if I need to submit let's say 100 apps in a month with a Google Sign-in functionality, I don't want to create 100 apps on Firebase console. Can you guys think in something for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: So , it will work if i change my project package name and create new app in firebase and add SHA-1 key and update json in app?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Firebase assistant then:

- Delete your app in the Firebase console in the project settings.
- Back in Firebase assistant reconnect to the Firebase for any service.
- It will ask you to sync with the project. Click on Sync.
- The app with new package will be added and the `google-services.json` file will be automatically updated.

Also note that the package name of the `applicationId` value in the `build.gradle` file is considered.

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

There's a better way of resolving this issue.The error can be as result of you having a GoogleService Json file in your app folder, All you need to do is; try and locate your google-service.json file under app folder, and change the package_Id to the new package_id you have created; Save, Do a Clean and Rebuild Project, your problem would be resolve. Hope this will help you. It works for me. You can kindly votes if this also help you. Thanks

Comment: Changing the package name in the json file is not enough, other information also need to be changed, so the best way is to create new app in the same project and use the new json file.

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 it depends on how you import and synchronized your project when you placed your Firebase Gson file in your app folder. What i pointed out, actually  worked for me, and there's no one way of getting a results. and Note; the above error message, always pop ups when you change your package_name, after you have already placed your generated GsonFile from firebase, and it popsUp the error, because the package_name, is no longer corresponding with what is inside the GsonFile. So it need to be change to the recent package_name.Hope you get my point. you don't need to vote it down.thanks

Comment: Yes it works, but it shouldn't. It makes no sense that an app declared with one package name and registered in firebase with different package name, and they are still connected to each other. That's definitely a bug from Google and there are no guaranties that this won't break in the future. Please edit your answer so I can unvote and apologies.

Comment: FIY, here is the official stand from Google regarding this issue: "To explain why it works based on the steps you did, the client app will still receive the message because FCM refers to the App ID, which is auto-generated from the app registration, in sending messages. With that, it is not recommended to manually alter the configuration files by changing the package name of an app. This can affect the notification delivery reports where the send counts coming from the intended app may not get some numbers.". They also say that this will change in the future.