# Google sign-in error with Firebase Auth UI after upgrade

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was using an older version of firebase auth ui successfully but after upgrading to the latest releases I receive the following error while trying to login with Google:

```
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 10, message: 10: 
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:106)
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.AuthMethodPickerActivity.onActivityResult(AuthMethodPickerActivity.java:225)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Facebook and email sign in is fine.

I am using these dependencies in my app gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.32.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

And the following in my project level gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Login activity:

```
public class ActivityLoginView extends ActivityBase {

// Misc
public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
public static final String TAG = "ActivityLoginView";

public ActivityLoginViewModel activityLoginViewModel;

private static final String PRIVACY_POLICY_URL = "https://www.editedout.com/pages/privacy";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activityLoginViewModel = new ActivityLoginViewModel(this);

    if (!activityLoginViewModel.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Google Play Services");
        alertDialog.setMessage("This app requires Google Play Services to be installed and enabled");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();

    } else {

        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        // See if user is logged in already
        if (currentUser != null) {

            // User already signed in
            if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(currentUser.getUid());
                Crashlytics.setUserName(currentUser.getDisplayName());
                Crashlytics.setUserEmail(currentUser.getEmail());
            }

            activityLoginViewModel.saveUserToFirebase();

        } else {

            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                            .setLogo(R.drawable.loginlogo)
                            .setAvailableProviders(getSelectedProviders())
                            .setPrivacyPolicyUrl(PRIVACY_POLICY_URL)
                            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);

        }
    }
}

public void startMain() {

    if (SPManager.getBoolean(this, SPManager.kOnBoardShown)) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityHomePage.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {

        startActivity(ActivityOnBoard.newIntent(this));

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        handleSignInResponse(resultCode, data);

    }
}

private void handleSignInResponse(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

    // Successfully signed in
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        activityLoginViewModel.saveUserToFirebase();

    } else {
        // Sign in failed
        if (response == null) {
            // User pressed back button
            showSnackbar(R.string.sign_in_cancelled);
            return;
        }

        if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
            showSnackbar(R.string.no_internet_connection);
            return;
        }

        showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_error);
        Log.e(TAG, "Sign-in error: ", response.getError());
    }
}

private List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> getSelectedProviders() {

    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> selectedProviders = new ArrayList<>();

    selectedProviders.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder()
            .build());

    selectedProviders.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder()
            .build());

    selectedProviders.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder()
            .setRequireName(true)
            .setAllowNewAccounts(true)
            .build());

    //selectedProviders
    //        .add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());

    return selectedProviders;

}

public void showSnackbar(@StringRes int errorMessageRes) {

    View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    Snackbar.make(parentLayout, errorMessageRes, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finishAffinity();

}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fixed it. I forgot to add my new debug SHA1 to Firebase.

Comment: Me too. :) Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#getting-a-sha-256-hash-of-your-keystore

Comment: you save my day

Comment: Perfect! Just did the same mistake. You should mark your own answer as the accepted answer. 

Comment: Same here. Tip to get SHA1 certificate fingerprint if the app is not yet published in Google Play store: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vr7CLhQwpsk&t=174s

Answer (score 2):

Step1) generate SH1 from your android studio

Click on Gradle -> signingReport - > In the Run console you will able to see SH1 value
[image]

Step 2) add the SH1 to firebase console. (https://console.firebase.google.com)

Goto -> Your project name -> Settings -> General -> Add fingerprints

add SH1 what we generated in step 1 and save

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you should add to your `build.gradle` file the following implementation:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'
```

If you are using Firebase authentication, you should also add:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'`
```

Don't also forget to add your debug SHA1 fingerprint to Firebase Console.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help. Its not mentioned in the documentation: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md

Answer (score 0):

For my case it is because I removed the keystore for the debug buildType.

As far as I know the SHA-1 is generated according to your keystore, and if you don't specify a keystore for your debug build, Android Studio will use a generated one automatically which of course has a different SHA-1.

Simply re-including the keystore worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

for me,
I activated some sign in method that I don't use on firebase authentication part.

check if you "enabled" some sign-in method that you don't use. :)
[image]

Comment: Add more detail

Comment: @paul_f hi there, added  :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked that I was using the correct debug and release keys but I was still getting this error. My issue was that when I released the app in the play store I had to refactor the package name. Therefore, Firebase no longer recognized my app.

Since Firebase doesn't allow you to change the package name you'll have to "add app" within the project. No need to re-add your keys, assuming they're the correct ones. More details on how to do that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201196/changing-firebase-package-name/40204186#40204186) answer