# Changing Firebase package name through new project don't work

Tags: android, firebase

I need to change the firebase package name, i found the answer [Changing Firebase Package Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201196/changing-firebase-package-name)
so I followed all the steps and created a new firebase project and included the new json but when I compile the app the error appears:

> No matching client found for package name
>   'silverbeach.app'

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="silverbeach.app"> ...
```

gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "silverbeach.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

} ...
```

All java classes and activities:

```
package silverbeach.app;
```

Firebase: Paketname
silverbeach.app

json:

```
  "package_name": "silverbeach.app"
```

All packages are spelled the same. So extra " " or some simple failures. I dont know what the problem is.
There is something strange, after I have done all steps and just put at the end in the gradle the old applicationId back it works but connect to the old firebase project, but I already changed the app with the new json of the new firebase project. I dont really understand how it can connect to the old project again...

Comment: after you have changed all the packages, try gradle sync , clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Are you sure you have to correct package name in your Firebase console?

Comment: @vimalraj done this but no effect on the problem

Comment: @AlexMamo yeah 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

If you change the application ID of your app, you need to three things:

1. Modify build.grade to use the new ID
2. Create a new Android app in the Firebase console to match the ID.
3. You need to download a whole new google-services.json file from the console after adding that app, and use that to configure your app.

The package name of your java files is irrelevant to all this.