# Firebase Admin SDK configured to access wrong app

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hopefully this isn't too similar to another question I posted. I am trying to read/write to my app's database from Firebase Functions using the Admin SDK. Been having issues. 
Here is the function:

```
exports.createAssetMux = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    console.log('data: ', data)

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.id).get()
    .then((doc) => {
        console.log('firestore document: ', doc)
        return {data: 'success'}
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error message: ', error)
        return {data: 'there was an issue'}
    });


});
```

And here is the response:

```
firestore document:  DocumentSnapshot {
>    _fieldsProto: undefined,
>    _ref: DocumentReference {
>      _firestore: Firestore {
>        _settings: [Object],
>        _settingsFrozen: true,
>        _serializer: [Serializer],
>        _projectId: 'live-from-868ea',
>        registeredListenersCount: 0,
>        _lastSuccessfulRequest: 1590544300258,
>        _backoffSettings: [Object],
>        _preferTransactions: false,
>        _clientPool: [ClientPool]
>      },
>      _path: ResourcePath { segments: [Array] },
>      _converter: {
>        toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore],
>        fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore]
>      }
>    },
>    _serializer: Serializer { createReference: [Function (anonymous)] },
>    _readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1590544300, _nanoseconds: 250711000 },
>    _createTime: undefined,
>    _updateTime: undefined
>  }
```

When I try to write to the db, or update anything, this is the response I get:

```
error message:  Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: no entity to update: app: "dev~my-firestore"
path <
  Element {
    type: "users"
    name: "kPuVNXsFFIyhs3Qad06B"
  }
>

  code: 5,
  details: 'no entity to update: app: "dev~my-firestore"\n' +
    'path <\n' +
    '  Element {\n' +
    '    type: "users"\n' +
    '    name: "kPuVNXsFFIyhs3Qad06B"\n' +
    '  }\n' +
    '>\n',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(1) { 'content-type' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  }
}
```

Note: My actual app name has been replaced with `my-firestore`, but I think the issue is with the `dev~` part before it, that part I left in place. Do I need to change some config setting? I've  checked in every config file I have and none of them contain the `dev~` part.

Comment: Could you please check the options explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201196/changing-firebase-package-name) and verify if you can change the name that it's being checked by your application?

Comment: I would really like to avoid creating a new project. But maybe it's not as difficult to go that route as I am thinking. Also, would this be the same if my target is iOS?

Comment: Hi @MarkRosenberg it should not be a big problem for you. Usually this is the best option for you to avoid this name issues, since the files are all created and configured based in one name. For iOS I'm not sure, but I think it should be the same, as they have configuration files created when you create the project as well.

Comment: My functions work with the admin.auth() functions. I can create a user object when a new account is created and it saves it to the appropriate database collection. Why would the issue be happening in one function but not the other, same file and everything? Also, I already have two apps for that project, and apparently that is the  maximum I am allowed per project.

Comment: Sorry, but your last comment didn't clarify much your situation. Could you please clarify the relation between this function using `admin.auth()` and your issue here? The one you are using here doesn't use this same method, which is a difference and the fact that you have two apps from the project, doesn't block you from creating a new one and trying to recreate the connection you have.

Comment: I just found a workaround using firebase serve --only functions. I was done messing around with emulators and all their bugginess.

Comment: Great to hear that you could find a solution. Please, consider posting the resolution as answer, in case other users face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was running `firebase emulators:start` which was starting up a dev db. It seems obvious now. Running `firebase serve --only functions` was the workaround I used if I didn't want to fuss with the emulators. It does connect right to your production db, so be careful.